# 301 redirect strip QUERY_STRING

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am planning to relaunch a website soon. Part of the relaunch is a switchover from Joomla! to Wordpress.

Besides some old pages, which will be redirected with some exact expression, I have a lot of pages, which will be redirected to the new root page.

Whats the right regular expression, if I want to redirect URLs like these:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/index.php?somevar=123&com_option=somevalue
http://www.somedomain.com/index.php?com_option=someothervalue
```

All the URLs have in common:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/index.php?
+
com_option
```

How can I redirect all those pages with one line of redirect code in .htaccess?

Comment: Have a look at: http://serverfault.com/questions/279996/how-do-you-redirect-urls-with-a-query-string-to-another-host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, that the site is gone live, I see that none of the answers to my questions worked out.

After some trial an error I found a solution:

By now Google offers a live-demo:

---

1) Go to google & search for "site:sqlxpert.de".

2) Click on one off the links having "option" in the URL.

3) You will be redirected to the new pages root - which in this case is the same domain and also an index.php, but the d*** QUERY_STRING is gone.

---

I needed a .htaccess snippet, which does the following (expressed in words):

```
If requested file is 
   INDEX.PHP or INDEX2.PHP 
AND 
   QUERY STRING contains "option"
then 301 REDIRECT to 
   http://www.sqlxpert.de/ 
WITHOUT any QUERY STRING
```

The solution:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option
RewriteRule ^index\.php http://www.sqlxpert.de/$1? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index2\.php http://www.sqlxpert.de/$1? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you do not need somevar and only want to carry over com_option

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule index.php(.*)com_option=(.*)$ http://newsite.com/index.php?com_option=$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I don't need to carry over anything, but need to identify the URLs, which have to be redirected by "index.php" + "com_option" or at least by "com_option"

Comment: So, just so I get it straight. You don't need to push the value of com_option to the new URL; you just want a page that had com_option in the url to redirect to your new homepage? If that is the case, just remove ?com_option=$2 from my entry. If you do need the value of com_option, then note that my entry (as it is now) will ignore everything except com_option. That will be added onto your new url - specified as http://newsite.com/index.php.

Comment: Humpf, now went live, but this is not the solution. Go Google search "site:sqlxpert.de" and follow one of the results with "index.php?com_option" in the URL.

You will get to the new site, but all the crap of QUERY_STRING is NOT beeing removed :-(

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)/the/old/domain/and/url/(.*) http://the/new/domain/and/path/$2
```